# I was asked to pay $412 just chanje from transferring my earnings from bank to Bitcoin wallet after I requested to withdraw my earnings

Tags: investing, scams

Someone called himself Mr Franklin Gordons told me to invest on his company website called bluegatefx.com from $300 I'll get $2900 in 4 of which I did then 2 days of trading then my investment just shoot upto $1414 from nowhere then my earnings started to increase with hire profits. On 4th day my trading stop immediately. Then I was asked my bank details or my wallet address so that I can receive my earnings but before I do that I must first pay 20% company commission fee of 3414 which was $683 then I couldn't have all that I paid $480 then my account manager told me to proceed with withdrawal but I mustn't withdraw all the money he told me to wait for the email to tell me the amount to withdraw. Then I received an email saying I can withdraw $2900 as my 20% commission company was incomplete. I proceed with the withdrawal they asked me COT code I did not have then they send me through email I withdraw the earnings from dashboard I waited for the money into my bank account within 24hr they send an email saying they've revised back the money due to my bank with the broker must be $3500 now they asking me to cash deposit $522 to them straight to make it $3500 for me to complete my withdrawal. So I want to know is this legitimate or scam?

Answer (score 13):

I'm sorry to say that you've almost certainly fallen victim to an [advanced fee scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam). They will have an unending stream of excuses as to why you can't withdraw your money yet, and each excuse will involve another fee or commission you need to pay. You can try reporting this to your bank or local law enforcement, but it's very unlikely that they will be able to assist. The scammers are probably in an entirely different country. If you've given the scammers any of your banking information you may want to close those accounts.

Comment: OK unfortunately I don't keep money on the account I gave them. So I'm safe.

Comment: @MorrisDBAkaRasta , depending on how much information you gave them, you aren't necessarily safe. If you just gave them your branch and account number you are probably fine. However, with enough information (say, your account password), they could make fraudulent deposits followed by withdrawals against the fraudulent deposits. When the bank figures out the deposits were fraudulent, **you** would be on the hook for any withdrawals because it is **your** account. This is unlikely, but some people are naive enough to give out their account passwords.